# How can I control the RGB of my canvas so that the Red and Green part of the gradient is the position of my mouse position divided by two?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

My HW instruction specifically calls for this: RGB where red is 0, green is the x-coordinate divided by 2, and blue is the y-coordinate divided by two. So far, my big canvas' colors are controlled by addColorStop functions but I'm not sure how to get the colors to change and how it should change. Any help is appreciated as I have been stuck on this for 2 days. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="big" onclick="myFiller(event);"; width="512" height="512"style="border: solid #000000;"></canvas>
<canvas id="small" width="100" height="100" style="background-color: #FF0000"></canvas>
<p id="para"></p>
<script>
// add eventListener
  var c = document.getElementById("big");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var rgbCanvas = ctx.createLinearGradient(c.width, c.height, 120,120);
  rgbCanvas.addColorStop(0, "red");
  rgbCanvas.addColorStop(0.5 ,"green");
  rgbCanvas.addColorStop(1, "blue");
  ctx.fillStyle = rgbCanvas;
  ctx.fillRect(0,0, 512, 512);

  var s = document.getElementById("small");
  var stx = s.getContext("2d");

  function myFiller(event) {
    console.log("running");
      // document.getElementById("big").innerHTML = style
    //  console.log(cData);
        var x = event.offsetX;
        var y = event.offsetY;
        var pixelContainer = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data; //pixelContainer grabs the context of "big" canvas but only one pixel worth
        console.log(pixelContainer); //just to see if pixelContainer is working
        console.log(pixelContainer[0],pixelContainer[1],pixelContainer[2],pixelContainer[3])
        //understand what this is later
        document.getElementById("big").innerHTML = "(" + pixelContainer[0] + " " + ")";
        var red = (pixelContainer[0]).toString(16);
        var green = (pixelContainer[1]).toString(16);
        var blue = (pixelContainer[2]).toString(16);
        document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "#"+ red+green+blue;

  }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please check your tags, javascript != java

Answer (score 2):

This is a straightforward way to have the background color of the canvas change on `mousemove`

rif: [mousemove MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event)

```js
  document.querySelector('canvas').addEventListener('mousemove', evt => 
    evt.target.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${evt.offsetX / 2}, ${evt.offsetY / 2}, 0)`
  )
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas width="512" height="512"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```